# Conveniently view scalar struct of vector fields in Variable Editor

Tags: matlab, struct

A scalar struct with fields consisting of vectors is more space efficient and faster to access/manipulate than an array of structs whose fields are scalars.  However, the former doesn't display well in the Variables Editor:

```
t=table([1;2;3],[4;5;6])

% A *long* struct array *will* show up in nice tabular format
x=table2struct(t,'ToScalar',false)
openvar('x')

% A scalar struct with *long* vector fields
% *won't* show up in nice tabular format
y=table2struct(t,'ToScalar',true)
openvar('y')
```

*Is* there a *convenient* way to view a scalar struct with long vector fields?  I find myself mostly examining data during code design, development, and troubleshooting, so I want method that doesn't require much (if any) creation of temporary code/variables to convert the data before viewing.  Whatever solution there is, I want to be able to use it on-the-fly, likely after breaking out in debugger mode.

Comment: How about just typing `struct2table(x)` at the command prompt? Tables display quite nicely, I think.

Comment: I do, sometimes.  But the advantage of the Variables Editor cannot be overstated, especially for long tables, and especially when you want to maintain visibility of a portion of the table as you unleash a meandering barrage of statements at the command line.  You can also easily muck with the table in the Variables Editor (sorting the table by one field after another at whim) without messing up your palette of command-line commands.

Comment: As a start to a possible solution, I know how to assign the result of a struct2table to a newly created diagnostic variable in the base workspace....if there was a way to throw that up on the Variable Editor without actually having to leave the current context and enter the base workspace, that would work.  It wouldn't be convenient, but it would work.

Comment: Actually, struct2table doesn't work at all if the fields of the struct consist of horizontal vectors.  Not a great situation, especially after having spent a bit of time converting over to scalar structs with vector fields.

Comment: I don't ever use the Variables Editor (or anything else besides the command prompt and the editor) -- I've gotten stuck in the 1990's... :)  But you can assign variables in the base workspace using `assignin`, and execute functions in the base workspace using `evalin`. Might be worth looking into.

Comment: That's what I was doing, but if the vector fields of a scalar struct are horizontal, then struct2table yields a one-row table with each entry under each variable consisting of a horizontal vector.  I'm rejigging all my code to work with tables from the start (the variables can be accessed in much the same way as vector fields in scalar structs), and then converting the tables to scalar structs with vector fields for accessing the data.  But once the conversion is done, there is no convenient display and manipulation via the Variables Editor.